# Multi onKeyPress functions event are not working in FF

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onkeypress

I have a from with two text box (username, cell #)

I have two JavaScript functions to validate the user input with `onKeyPress` but I don't know why it is not working in FF while it works fine in IE and Chrome!

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML><html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>JavaSCript Input Test</title>

<script>
/* Only numbers in mobile text-box */
function ValidateKeyNumber(event) 
{   
    var key=(event||window.event).keyCode;
    var allowed='0123456789';

    return allowed.indexOf(String.fromCharCode(key)) !=-1 ;
}
function ValidateKeyText(event) 
{   
    var key=(event||window.event).keyCode;
    var allowed='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ ';

    return allowed.indexOf(String.fromCharCode(key)) !=-1 ;
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form>
<label>Userame:</label>
<input type="text" size="30" name="Username" onKeyPress="return ValidateKeyText(event)" />
<br/><br/>
<label>Cell Number:</label>
<input type="text" name="cell" onKeyPress="return ValidateKeyNumber(event)"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Can you please help in this? 
Please I need the solution in JavaScript

Thanks in advance.

Comment: P.S. JavaScript is enabled in FF

Comment: ... but `keyCode` isn't enabled in FF, rather it's `which` ; ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
var key = event.which || event.keyCode || event.charCode;
```

Comment: @SULTAN  Put this before return (it's a check for the backspace key)                                           if(key==8){
     return true;
}